# Android set full width on custom layouts for menu

Tags: android

I'm trying to attach custom layout for menu items on DrawerLayout, but as you see menu items don't have full width and i can't resolve this problem

[image]

My menu layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <group android:id="@+id/groupOne">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/inbox"
            app:actionLayout="@layout/create_new"/>
    </group>
</menu>
```

and my custom layout for that as `create_new`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:gravity="center_vertical"
              android:paddingTop="5dp"
              android:paddingBottom="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:gravity="left|center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:background="#000"
        android:textColor="#fff"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, the only way that worked for me was to set `android:layout_width="100000dp"` on the custom layout's root view.

Ugly ugly hack, however.

Answer (score 0):

> **Add custom Spinner in Navigation menu / Navigation drawer / menu item.**
>
> 1) Create Menu Item in menu directory.

```
<menu>
>     <item
>         android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer_item3"
>         app:actionLayout="@layout/nav_drawer_home_spinner"
>         tools:ignore="MenuTitle,icon" /> 
</menu>
```

> 2)Navigation drawer where you can put all types of navigation drawer
>   here.
>   - header 
>   -menu with icon
>   -menu without icon
>   -custom menu item (Spineer)
>
> ```
> <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
>     android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
>     android:background="@color/md_white_1000"
>     tools:openDrawer="start">
>
>     <include
>         layout="@layout/app_bar_dashboard"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="match_parent" />
>
>     <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
>         android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer_container"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="match_parent"
>         android:elevation="0dp"
>         android:background="@color/md_white_1000"
>         android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
>         android:layout_gravity="start">
>
>         <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="match_parent"
>             android:fillViewport="true"
>             android:scrollbars="vertical"
>             android:background="@color/md_white_1000">
>
>             <LinearLayout
>                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
>                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
>                 android:orientation="vertical"
>                 android:background="@color/md_white_1000">
>
>
>                 <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
>                     android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer_with_icon"
>                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>                     android:layout_height="0dp"
>                     android:layout_weight="1"
>                     android:layout_gravity="center"
>                     android:elevation="0dp"
>                     android:background="@color/md_white_1000"
>                     app:itemTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
>                     app:itemIconTint="@color/colorAccent"
>                     app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_dashboard"
>                     android:theme="@style/NavigationViewStyle"
>                     app:menu="@menu/activity_dashboard_drawer"/>
>
>                 <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
>                     android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer_without_icon"
>                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                     android:background="@color/md_white_1000"
>                     app:itemTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
>                     android:elevation="0dp"
>                     android:layout_gravity="bottom"
>                     android:theme="@style/NavigationViewStyleOnlyText"
>                     app:menu="@menu/activity_dashboard_withouticon_drawer"/>
>
>                 <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
>                     android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer_spinner"
>                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                     android:elevation="0dp"
>                     android:layout_gravity="bottom"
>                     app:menu="@menu/activity_dashboard_spinner"/>
>
>             </LinearLayout>
>         </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
>     </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
> </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
> ```
>
> 3) Custom row_spinner_layout for putting your custom layout for menu
>   item of that navigation view.
>
> ```
> <LinearLayout
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:weightSum="1"
>     android:orientation="horizontal">
>
>     <ImageView
>         android:id="@+id/img_profilPic"
>         android:layout_width="0dp"
>         android:layout_weight="0.15"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:padding="3dp"
>         android:src="@drawable/profilepic" />
>          
>     <LinearLayout
>         android:layout_width="0dp"
>         android:layout_weight="0.7"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_gravity="center"
>         android:layout_margin="5dp"
>         android:orientation="vertical">
>
>         <TextView
>             android:id="@+id/tv_title"
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:textSize="18sp"
>             android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
>             android:text=""/>
>
>         <TextView
>             android:id="@+id/tv_subtitle"
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:textSize="12sp"
>             android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
>             android:text=""/>
>
>
>
>     </LinearLayout>
>
>
> </LinearLayout>
> ```